# Namespace Error in C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having errors appear in the Private Void Awake() & Private Void Start() 
sections on the script. If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.

The errors read:

> Expected  Class, delegate, enum, interface or struct. Type of
>   Namespace definition, or end of file detected.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] m_Tanks;

private float m_gameTime = 0;
public float GameTime { get { return m_gameTime; } }
public enum GameState
{
    Start,
    Playing,
    GameOver
};
private GameState m_GameState;
public GameState State { get { return m_GameState; } }
}

private void Awake()
{
m_GameState = GameState.Start;
}
private void Start()
{
for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
{
    m_Tanks[i].SetActive(false);
}
m_TimerText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
m_Exit.gameObject.SetActive(false);
m_HighScores.LoadScoresFromFile();
}
void Update()
{
switch (m_GameState)
{
case GameState.Start:
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return) == true)
    {
        m_GameState = GameState.Playing;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Tanks[i].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    break;
case GameState.Playing:
    bool isGameOver = false;
    m_gameTime += Time.deltaTime;
    int seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(m_gameTime);
    if (OneTankLeft() == true)
    {
        isGameOver = true;
    }
    else if (IsPlayerDead() == true)
    {
        isGameOver = true;
    }
    if (isGameOver == true)
    {
        m_GameState = GameState.GameOver;
    }
    break;
case GameState.GameOver:
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return) == true)
    {
        m_gameTime = 0;
        m_GameState = GameState.Playing;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Tanks[i].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    break;
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
{
    Application.Quit();
}
}
private bool OneTankLeft()
{
int numTanksLeft = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
{
    if (m_Tanks[i].activeSelf == true)
    {
        numTanksLeft++;
    }
}
return numTanksLeft <= 1;
}
private bool IsPlayerDead()
{
for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
{
    if (m_Tanks[i].activeSelf == false)
    {
        if (m_Tanks[i].tag == "Player")
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: It'd be easier to identify where you have imbalanced braces if you indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly closing the curly braces ({}) in your file.

Your class `GameManager` ends at line 18 and your method `Awake` starts in nowhere, which is not correct.

Methods need to be placed inside classes. That's your problem.